# multiple values in a field that could be dynamic

Tags: sql, database, schema

I have to design a schema where I have to depict what effect is caused due to interaction of 2 or more(infinite) drugs.. when it is just 2 drugs its easy . I can have a table with drugid1, drugid2 and interaction id... but how do I support this for multiple drug interaction? Please help

Comment: Use a normalized database design.  If you don't know what that is, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.  Also bear in mind that there could be more than one effect for any interation.

Answer (score 0):

You need three tables, one for the drugs, one for the combinations, one for the relation:

- table drug: drug_id (PK), drug_name, ...
- table drugmix: drugmix_id (PK), effect
- table drugsinmix: drug_id, drugmix_id

Comment: How does this work if a combination has more than one effect?

Comment: @user3438489, the druginmix table solves the problem you envision.

Comment: So I don't know what you mean by *infinite drugs*. I thought you meant it can be any number of drugs in a combination. What else do you mean?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: That depends. There can be a text field in drugmix where you describe all effects that can or will occur. If you want to have a list of effects instead, then you would have an effects table and a bridge table between drugmix and effect of course.

Comment: drug id's 1,2,3,4,5 together can cause death... drug ids 1,5,7,6,2,3,4,1 can cause brain damage and so on

Comment: @user3438489: the drugsinmix table can have many entries for each drug_id. This is what it is for. A so-called n:m relation.

Comment: So the sequence is important? drugs 1 + 2 + 3 can be okay, but 1 + 3 + 2 has an effect, for instance? Then the drugsinmix table needs an additional order number.